# Are there any Armor Enchantments that are specifically good against Outsiders?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting, armor

My DM would like to create magical items that are specifically designed to fight angels and demons.  For weapons, we are using the "[Bane](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/bane/)" template, using a custom category of "Outsiders (Angels and Demons)".

Are there any armor enchantments available that will give specific benefits or protections versus Angels and/or Demons?

I know that this is a rare category, so please also feel free to include any enchantments that are good versus outsiders, a specific type of outsider, or a specific creature type of any kind, and my DM is comfortable changing those to "Demons and Angels".

Comment: Can you please clarify what system you are asking about? You have both Pathfinder and 3.5 tagged. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Yes, my dm will allow items from either official ruleset.

Comment: Is it only items that you are using from 3.5 or are you using game rules from it as well? Which rules are you primarily using to play the game? PF or 3.5? Or both?

Comment: Pathfinder mostly. Some 3.5 spells. 3.5 Warlock, bard, and warblade.  It's a 3.5 game that has been slowly converting to pathfinder.  It's always going to be a hybrid. For the context of this question, I won't have any difficulty making adjustments to an item from either 3.5 or pf to make it coherent with our rule system.

Comment: @Weasemunk Just as an FYI, if you see someone tag something with confusing system tags, it is better to ask them why than to just assume the system tags and correct them based on assumptions. In this case, the game is a hybrid of the two versions so I think tagging as both is appropriate. It's not a big deal though I'm just letting you know so you know for the future.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Thanks and sorry about that. I always see the notifications that the author has to approve the edit first and assumed it's correct to just propose an edit. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Weasemunk proposing an edit is certainly fine! though in that case it goes to any user with enough reputation to approve an edit (which is what happened), not just the OP, to approve it. In the end, no harm done. It was an easy fix and we all learned something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an armor property which is similar to Bane called [Defiant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/defiant/). It provides an additional +2 AC and DR 2/- against creatures of a specific type. There is also a specific armor which could be useful against outsiders, the [Forsaken Banded Mail](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/forsaken-banded-mail/), which provides bonuses against creatures empowered by deities. Other than those two I don't believe there are any armor enchantments that would be specifically useful against both good and evil outsiders.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the [Defiant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/defiant/) property mentioned by Kyle Doyle, you might consider the [Deathless](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/deathless) armor property, which reduces any positive or negative energy damage that the wearer takes by 10. While not all angels and demons use this sort of aligned energy damage, it could be very helpful depending on the types of angels and demons that you typically encounter. As a bonus, Deathless armor also gives a 25% chance to avoid taking a negative level as a side effect of an attack, though that's more of an undead thing than an outsider thing.